# How to reload/refresh html page in browser automatically after change? on Windows

Tags: html, node.js

Is there any way how to refresh (local?) page in browser (Chrome?) during development after change and save on disk? I think node.js is the direction?

Comment: This is rather vague. Chrome does have a refresh button, that's normally how you would do that. Why would you want to make it more complicated than that?

Comment: not complicated but more comfortable

Comment: Yes, it's very handy. I use it all the time in dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use gulp for that. Install gulp (`npm install gulp --save-dev`) and use gulp.watch to watch file changes, then use `browser-sync` (npm install...) to reload the browser when files change.

Note that gulp takes some getting used to. See https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp for more info.

Comment: great. it's working (even without gulp i think)
the command after install (```browser-sync``` is: 
```browser-sync start --server -w```)
in directory where is my html. Tool will inform you that you have to put little code into your page.

Comment: awesome ;) good to know you can use it without the whole gulp toolchain.

Comment: not sure about that gulp, i have installed it long time ago and I didn't do nothing with it today... i just installed browser-sync and executed the command... that's all. works nicely